# How to retrieve data using ajax and without going to post page? Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm new to using ajax. For example after field `title` is filled, I want to search in database for specific data and return more fields based on that input. So far I can only receive my `title` data in /ajax/post page by pressing get data/post data or submit button. How do I receive my `title` input and data from `Route::post` while/after filling `title`? If I remove `Form::model` and `Form::close()` I do get my dummy data from `Route::post` without page refresh by clicking `Post data` button, but without title value.

I'm aware that checking `title` field involves some jQuery/js, but I have no idea how to actually bring that `title` field into my `route` to do some database searching and return some data with it.

View:

```
            {!! Form::model($project = new \App\Project, ['url' => 'ajax/post', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
            <!-- pass through the CSRF (cross-site request forgery) token -->
            <meta name="csrf-token" content="<?php echo csrf_token() ?>" />

            <!-- some test buttons -->
            <button id="get">Get data</button>
            <button id="post">Post data</button>

            <div class="form-group padding-top-10">
              {!! Form::label('title', 'Title') !!}
              {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title']) !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::submit('Submit Button', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Ajax script:

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } });
    function onGetClick(event)
    {
        // we're not passing any data with the get route, though you can if you want
        $.get('/ajax/get', onSuccess);
    }
    function onPostClick(event)
    {
        // we're passing data with the post route, as this is more normal
        $.post('/ajax/post', {payload:'hello'}, onSuccess);
    }
    function onSuccess(data, status, xhr)
    {
        console.log(data, status, xhr);
        // JSON is deserialised into an object
        console.log(String(data.value).toUpperCase())
    }
    $('button#get').on('click', onGetClick);
    $('button#post').on('click', onPostClick);
</script>
```

And in route:

```
    Route::get('/ajax/view', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'AjaxController@view']);
    Route::get('/ajax/get', function () {
        $data   = array('value' => 'some get');
        return  Response::json($data);
    });
    Route::post('/ajax/post', function () {
        $data   = array('value' => 'some data', 'input' => Request::input());
        return  Response::json($data);
    });
```

Comment: Do u want to fetch the data as u're typing the "Title"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to implement the jquery keypress function.

so here is you js:

```
$("input.title").keypress(function(){
    var title = $(this).val();

    // now do the ajax request and send in the title value
    $.get({
        url: 'url you want to send the request to',
        data: {"title": title}, 
        success: function(response){
           // here you can grab the response which would probably be 
           // the extra fields you want to generate and display it
        }
    });
});
```

as far as in Laravel you can pretty much treat it the same as a typical request except you will return json:

```
Route::get('/url-to-handle-request', function({
    // lets say what you need to populate is 
   //authors from the title and return them

   $title = Route::get('title'); // we are getting the value we passed in the ajax request

    $authors = Author::where('title' ,'=', $title)->get();

    return response()->json([
        'authors' => $authors->toArray();
    ]);
}));
```

Now I would probably use a controller and not just do everything within the route but I think you'll get the basic idea.

Comment: why did you use $.get({? Is there a difference between using $.post({ and $.get({?. Shouldn't we use post then we are giving back some data?

Comment: @Dancia the main difference between get and post is what your doing with your request. for example everytime you search something on google google sends a get request with the parameters you sent and retrieves the result. Now if your signing up for gmail that would be a post request since google is not getting any data back. Also for get request the request appears in the url so if its sensitive data I would always do a post request instead.