# Text Field autofill in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I am trying to fill the second text box based on the input given to the first text box. For example, when the user gives the user id his other details should be filled automatically in the text fields from the database.

Comment: Welcome. Show some code please

Comment: are you using Ajax to achieve this.. take a look at the answer in this link ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969630/how-to-retrieve-data-using-ajax-and-without-going-to-post-page-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to auto fix the users details by just entering the id and not refreshing the page you should better dive into AJAX. Use ajax on value enter just submit it to the any method function where you get info by id then populate it to the input field by name, id whichever you want

Comment: I am beginner for ajax, so could you please help me?

Comment: As you dont have any code try reading http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp but int laravel you should pass the csrf token for the post request